# Redirecting url to a folder

Tags: javascript

I had a Joomla websites once upon a time which is still in root directoy. And recently I have contstructed my website in a folder with html 5 by myself..

To redirect my url to my new folder I have found this and had successfull with it : 
an index.html containing =

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
function goto(){
window.location.href="x.href.php"
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="goto()">
</body>
</html>
```

But now I see that my joomla pages can still be reached and it wouldnt be a problem unless Google still shows pages from old version (joomla one) .

How can I redirect all pages/links to the new folder? 
Can this be done via Javascript again?

Comment: Google redirect. Best solution are the html header and the .htaccess files.

Comment: Use robots.txt to block search engines to that old pages.

Answer (score 0):

Since Joomle uses Apache, use .htaccess files to redirect to your new website.
Here's an example :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: i just pasted it from one of my files